# can an array in JS be saved by a hacker

Tags: javascript, json

i am filling an array in js through json and php. my resulting array is 2 dimensional which has userid and username.

now, while debugging, i can use chrome's debugger and view the array elements (by adding WATCH).

and it occured to me, if i can see the elements of my array, can a hacker look at the elements?

and further, can the hacker save this array on his hard drive?

thanks

Comment: Everybody can open his developer console and see your javascript/DOM. You don't have to be a *hacker* to do this

Comment: Yes he could save it if he can see it (copy paste for example)

Comment: If the data goes out over HTTP from your server to a client… then yes, anyone can see it, even without having to use watch statements.

Comment: the general theory is, if you can do it then a person who is experienced in many more things will be able to, if youre so worried use hashing

Comment: then how do i protect the array?

Comment: Why would you protect your own username and id ?

Comment: "Protect" from whom under what circumstances against what? The only 100% protection is not to send it over the wire in the first place.

Comment: @mansooriqbal Don't send it to the client…?

Comment: @ImmortalDude can u send me a link where i can learn what is hashing and how to do it?

Comment: Don't bother with hashing. The client can't use the data if it's been hashed, and if it can't use the data, you might as well not send it in the first place.

Comment: @mansooriqbal you need to know some server side language for utilizing hashing, you can use php, its simple for learning quickly, as for your hashing you can read about how to use php to do it [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb79mN6pbSAhUEt48KHXQ_BHQQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.password-hash.php&usg=AFQjCNFroQbAg7_BuAeD_rY3jumHWLAQ2A)\

Comment: @ImmortalDude thank u!

Answer (score 3):

You never want to make sensitive data available to other users. Use something more secure, such as the user's id or unique email, then find the appropriate users in your database and handle your logic server side..

Answer (score 2):

Answer is yes he can do it too by opening his developer console.
Then yes of course he could save it just by copy + paste the content for example.